# How to solve RIOI_2_3 in spoj ?

Tags: graph, breadth-first-search

I have been pondering upon how to apply BFS to it without any success.
Link to the problem http://www.spoj.com/problems/RIOI_2_3/

Comment: Please can you share what you have tried? We can help you.

Answer (score 0):

This is a nyc explanation for the problem..
Give a try..
https://shinghalrishabh.wordpress.com/2015/03/12/bfsbitmask-usage-on-spoj/

Comment: Try to give an explanation inline instead of directly giving external links. The reason being that the link might not work later.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is a classic example of bfs + bitmasking problems. I'll recommend to try it first. If still you are stuck, below are two solutions. Please comment for any further clarification.

[Solution 1](https://github.com/nyctophiliacme/Spoj-Solutions/blob/master/RIOI_2_3.cpp)

[Solution 2](https://github.com/nyctophiliacme/Spoj-Solutions/blob/master/RIOI_2_3(1).cpp)